# Which version of Solaris for my Sun Sparc system?

Tags: solaris, sparc

I'm about to buy a used Sun Sparc machine (Sun Blade 2500 Ultrasparc IIIi 1,28Ghz) in order to use it as a personal development server. Problem is, it is sold without any OS. I would like to install a Solaris system on it, but I don't know what I'm looking for. I think Solaris 10 should work, since it was released the same year than the machine, but I'm not sure. And could the newer Solaris 11 work on it?

Comment: I finally found the definitive answer on Oracle's hardware compatibility list (HCL): http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/data/sol/index.html

Comment: If your goal is to develop on Solaris, you could always use Solaris x86 on an x86 desktop (check HCL), or run it in a VM (ie: with VirtualBox).

Comment: Why all those downvotes? What's wrong with my question?

Comment: Turns out I cannot delete my seemingly unwelcomed question, because "other people have invested time and effort to answer it", so I guess I will just have to suck up all those nice downvotes. SE these days...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oracle dropped support for US IIIi processors in Solaris 11 ([official announcement](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/end-of-notices/eonsolaris11-392732.html)). Solaris 10 will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

That should be capable of running Solaris 10 have a look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Blade_%28workstation%29) and there is official documentation from SUN [here too](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19127-01/blade2500.ws/817-5121-14/index.html)

Answer (score 2):

[This wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Blade_%28workstation%29) seems to indicate the Solaris 10 is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the answer, so I just googled' it.

The first result is [a wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Blade_%28workstation%29), which says that Solaris 10 is supported and that Solaris 11 is unknown. My guess is that it's unsupported to run Solaris 11 on it, but that it might work.

Comment: I also tried to goole it, but for some reason, I didn't see that Wikipedia page...